# Unable to drag and drop to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop

I have been draging and dropping from Windows Explorer to Eclipse since I've started using it, and now find myself unable to do so. When I drag a .java file over my package, the mouse cursor stays a circle with a diagonal bar through it and dropping does nothing.
I have tried to change my workspace, create a fresh new workspace, deleted eclipse and redownloaded it. It still doesn't work. Making Eclipse run as admin doesn't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out it was due to viewing the project in **Project Explorer** instead of **Package Explorer**.

Right click on a project > Show in > Package Explorer

You'll be able to drag-drop again at this point.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least two workarounds:

- Use the menu File -> Import -> General -> File System
- or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in Windows Explorer, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in the Package Explorer of Eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue when Eclipse was running as Administrator. Setting it back just worked.

Comment: Similar issue I faced and tried with lot of drag and drop API, but DnD not worked for me, remove Eclipse Administrator permission at start, Simply worked for me...Thanks you saved a week for me...

Comment: drag & drop files into eclipse stopped working yesterday.  Unchecked 'Run as Administrator' from the shortcut and now its working again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem when trying to drag-drop image file directly from explored zip. After I extracted the zip, drag-drop worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the missing marketplace client. 
It is noticeable when help -> Eclipse Marketplace is missing. 
I installed it with help -> Install new Software -> Update Site for 2018-09 -> Eclipse Marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Extract all files from zip folder. It worked for me.