# JavaFX Drag Drop Window Not Responding

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying a simple Java FX program which creates a Window and all I need is to add the ability of reading a dropped file. I have got the following code snippet which doesn't throw any error but neither let me drop anything. When I try to drop a file, it shows a Red cursor(not allowed windows cursor)

I am on Windows 8 machine and JDK Version 8.0_60. Not sure what the problem is. Is there something wrong with the code? Am I missing something?

What I have tried -

1. Tried changing the Transfer Mode
2. Tried checking the file permissions

Sorry, if there is a fooling mistake in the code as I am new to JavaFx.

Here goes the code -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragMe extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Please Drag Your File Here.");
        Label dropped = new Label("");
        VBox dragTarget = new VBox();
        dragTarget.getChildren().addAll(label,dropped);
        dragTarget.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != dragTarget
                        && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                }
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        dragTarget.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;
                if (db.hasString()) {
                    dropped.setText(db.getString());
                    success = true;
                }
                /* let the source know whether the string was successfully 
                 * transferred and used */
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            }


        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(dragTarget);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Testing the Drap File");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Had a discussion with NwDx and we tried to figure out the drag-drop in different scenarios.

1. If the file is dragged from Eclipse File Tree, the dropping is allowed
2. If the file is dragged from any other location e.g. Desktop, it doesn't work
3. Tried creating a new Workspace for eclipse, but didn't work.
4. Tried drag-drop in MS Word, and it works fine.
5. Tried creating a JAR and running it, and it works fine.

Tried starting Eclipse as Administrator but no luck.

**SOLVED**

Running Eclipse as Administrator causes this issue. Running normally works! Thanks NwDx for your code.
([Unable to drag and drop to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124102/unable-to-drag-and-drop-to-eclipse))

Comment: Surely you want `event.getDragboard().hasFiles()` in the `dragOver` handler and `db.getFiles()` in the `dragDropped` handler, if you are dropping a file?

Comment: I thought that but even copying and pasting the text is not working. I can surely give a try to what you suggested.

Comment: I tried your example as it is currently written, and selecting and dragging some plain text (from Eclipse) worked fine (on Mac OSX 10.9.5 / JDK 1.8.0u60).

Comment: Yeah. It should work fine. I am not getting it to work on my machine though. Not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: Post your platform (OS with version and JDK version) in your question and see if anyone can check on the same setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I've got a solution working, hopefully to you too. I've changed the way you asked for `setOnDragOver`, maybe a file do not have `hasString()` to be true, so I changed it to `event.getDragboard().hasFiles()`and changed Transfertype to Copy. But you are able to change it like you want. After that you need to get the Files from the Dragboard (you may could have dragged more than one). And in my simple example I only grab the first one and display it's absolute path.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragMe extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Please Drag Your File Here.");
        Label dropped = new Label("");
        Label content = new Label();
        VBox dragTarget = new VBox();
        dragTarget.getChildren().addAll(label, dropped, content);
        dragTarget.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != dragTarget && event.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
                    /*
                     * allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses
                     */
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                }
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        dragTarget.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                List<File> files = (ArrayList<File>) db.getContent(DataFormat.FILES);

                boolean success = false;
                if (files != null) {
                    File file = files.get(0);
                    dropped.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    success = true;
                }
                /*
                 * let the source know whether the string was successfully
                 * transferred and used
                 */
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            }

        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(dragTarget);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Testing the Drap File");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: App]

Comment: Well, that's weird and I feel stupid. I tried Notepad/Notepad++ as well but didn't get it to work. While I was trying for file, I eventually ended up with Text. Is there any special rule of dragging for file as well? As, the same is happening with the file drag and drop. I am simply trying to show the path of the file in the window.

Comment: Though, I can't even get Notepad++ to work. I am just able to use Eclipse to drag the text.

Comment: And I am still struggling to get it work. Its not allowing me to drag the file. Show the red cursor.

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot Did you recognize my change in `setOnDragOver`?

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot Sometimes there are some Antimalware or Antivirus Software out, that randomize or clears the content of your clipboard. Maybe you have one installed?

Comment: Yes, I simply copied your code and ran it. Again, it ran without issues but not letting me drag a file to the window. Check this - > https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjXpQj_pGRtYVcwd1NvVFR2NDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No, I don't have any antivirus or any background process running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90459/discussion-between-nwdx-and-bhush-techidiot).

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. I am running from IntelliJ 2020.1 beta on Java 14 with JavaFX 14.

Answer (score 1):

To add to NwDx answer, the drag and drop won't work if Eclipse is ran as Administrator.

Ran it normally and got it working!

Reference - [Unable to drag and drop to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124102/unable-to-drag-and-drop-to-eclipse)

Comment: Good to know that you found the real reason of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your involvement as well :)